# Hide several sections from TOC in book

Tags: table-of-contents

The question is on the title - How to hide (exclude) all sections of the certain chapter in book class document (pdflatex)? Thanks in advance

Comment: Of a certain chapter? Shall this be done automatically?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer really I'd like to hide all sections from 2 chapters from the toc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is

```
\newcommand{\emptysection}[1]{%
    \begingroup\renewcommand\addcontentsline[3]{}%
    \section{#1}\endgroup%
}
```

Comment: Yes, but this won't work for `\subsection` etc. (if needed!)

Comment: Ok, then \newcommand{\emptysubsection}[1]{%
    \begingroup\renewcommand\addcontentsline[3]{}%
    \subsection{#1}\endgroup%
}

Answer (score 4):

Improved version, with automatic removal from ToC using a user-defined `\HideFromTOC{2,4,8}` command, the numbers being the chapter numbers:

```
\documentclass{book}


\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\newcommand{\hidelevel}{0}  % 0 means chapter and part only
\newcounter{backuptocdepth}

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setcounter{backuptocdepth}{\value{tocdepth}}%
}


\ExplSyntaxOn%

\clist_new:N \g_chapterhide_clist

\newcommand{\HideFromTOC}[1]{%
  \clist_gclear:N \g_chapterhide_clist%
  \clist_gset:Nx \g_chapterhide_clist {#1}
}

\newcommand{\checkiftohide}[1]{%
  \tl_set:Nx \l_tmpa_tl {#1}
  \clist_if_in:NVT \g_chapterhide_clist {\l_tmpa_tl}{%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{\hidelevel}}
  }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff
\makeatletter

\xpatchcmd{\@chapter}{%
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
}{%
  \checkiftohide{\the\numexpr\value{chapter}+1}%
  \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
}{\typeout{Success}}{\typeout{Patch failure}}

\xpretocmd{\chapter}{%
  \setcounter{tocdepth}{\value{backuptocdepth}}%
  \addtocontents{toc}{\protect\setcounter{tocdepth}{\number\value{tocdepth}}}% Write the old value back to ToC
}{}{} % Restore the old tocdepth counter value


\makeatother

\HideFromTOC{2,4,8}


\begin{document}


\tableofcontents


\chapter{First}

\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}

\chapter{Second}

\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}


\chapter{Third}
\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}



\chapter{Fourth}

\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}

\chapter{Fifth}

\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}


\chapter{Sixth}

\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}


\chapter{Seventh}

\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}

\chapter{Eighth}

\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}


\end{document}
```

The output:

[image]

Old-Version

A first version with `tocdepth` set to `0` temporarily and restored later on.

```
\documentclass{book}



\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}

\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}

\chapter{Second}

\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}


\chapter{Third}
\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}
\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}


\addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}}

\chapter{Fourth}

\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}

\chapter{Fifth}

\section{Foo}
\section{Bar}


\end{document}
```

Comment: My book has parts also. I've tried this \addtocontents{toc}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{0}}, but it gives an error with my books compiliation. But your MWE works fine

Comment: @OlgaK: You did not provide a compilable example, unfortunately

Comment: I know. Just working with pre-defined complicated publisher's conditions. They gave Cls file, probably my fail follows from cls-settings of TOC. Thank you, Christian, so kind!

Comment: @OlgaK: It's no `book.cls` then.

Comment: it's specialbook.cls, you're right

Comment: @OlgaK: And there's no chance to get `specialbook.cls` ???

Comment: probably via email?

Comment: @OlgaK: See my mail address on my profile page

Comment: @OlgaK: I've got the mail. I'll check and reply by mail, not posting here of course!